# Return statement not working in Python 3.4.3

Tags: python

For some reason or another, Python interpreter is not modifying my return statement value within the function when accessed by another function.

```
x=10

def example():

    global_variable_x = x
    print(" i know i can access it", global_variable_x)
    global_variable_x +=5
    print(" woa, i can modify it" ,global_variable_x)
    return global_variable_x

example()

def modify_another_function():
    return 10*example()

modify_another_function()
```

Comment: `print example()` and you will see that it does return.

Comment: It's necessary in a question like this to explain what you *expected* it to return, and what it did.

Comment: It gives me invalid syntax when I've added print before example()

Comment: You're using python 3, change it to `print(example())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program works as intended.

You define `global_variable_x = x` and give it the name global_variable, but in fact it's a local variable. The easiest way to be able to keep the data persistent is to modify `x` or to use classes and write it to a class variable.

To give you some **more detailed** information:

```
    x=10

def example():

    global_variable_x = x
    print(" i know i can access it", global_variable_x)
    global_variable_x +=5
    print(" woa, i can modify it" ,global_variable_x)
    return global_variable_x
 example()
```

It might be abstracted but just to give you some idea:

- You will put x = 10 on the programming stack.
- You will call example()
- The example() function call will create a new stack frame for that
  function call putting `global_variable_x` on it.
- When the function call hits the `return` statement the stack frame will
  be removed and the only thing that    remains is `x`.
- The second time you run `example()` it will create a new    stack
  frame, put `global_variable_x` again on it and instantiate it    again
  with the value of `x`, being 10.

The problem here is related to **scoping**, I suggest you to take a look at: [this blog](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/python-variable-scope-notes/)

Answer (score 0):

The print inside example will always show the same thing.

This is because in the context of `example` nothing changes.

The difference will only be visible outside of `example` inside `modify_another_function`. The multiplication with 10 is happening outside of `example`, if you change `modify_another_function` to this you'll see the difference:

```
def modify_another_function():
    return print 10*example()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did add the "print" statement before but python gives me invalid syntax !

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that what you're getting is:

```
 i know i can access it 10
 woa, i can modify it 15
 i know i can access it 10
 woa, i can modify it 15
```

I'm assuming you wanted something like:

```
 i know i can access it 10
 woa, i can modify it 15
 i know i can access it 15
 woa, i can modify it 20
```

You can get that by doing:

```
x=10

def example():
    print(" i know i can access it", x)
    x +=5
    print(" woa, i can modify it", x)
    return x

example()

def modify_another_function():
    return 10*example()

modify_another_function()
```

But you can't do it the way you're doing because numbers are values and immutable. So if you copy them, you're only copying their value, not a reference to them.